# Redirect from .com to .net

Tags: google, redirects, 301-redirect

If I 301 redirect page from `.com` to `.net`
will I lose some traffic or page rank on Google or will everything still be the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you redirect all the old pages to the relevant new pages with 301 redirects, you shouldn't be losing any traffic or page rank because this is what Google recommends.

Also, use the [change of address tool](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/83106?hl=en) in Google Search Console Tool to move your website to a new domain:

[image: Google Search Console - Change of Address]

Comment: @w3dk I redirect .com to .net so page and content is same just extension is diferent

Comment: @nikola99 That's why you will need to use this extension and have proper 301 redirect to relevant pages.